# Do I need to use sterilized jars straight away?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, utensils

When making jams and preserves you obviously need to sterilize the jars. After the jars have been sterilized do you need to use them straight away or can you sterilize them in advance and keep them for when you're ready to use them?

Comment: @Aaronut: done... I was just looking at that question in the home page thinking "that doesn't look right" :)

Comment: of course, if one is not American it becomes sterelised :)

Comment: @Pulse: It's still spelled with an *i* after the *r*!

Comment: Yea, that was a typo, my bad :)

Answer (score 6):

You should be packing the jars while they are still hot, for rawpacked or hot-packed products. For hot-packed products, this helps avoid the risk of the jar breaking.

For great instructions on how to can at home, see the [National Center for Home Food Preservation](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/).

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd sterilise my jars as they are needed. Doing so ensures there are no bacteria and also keeps the jars slightly warm. Placing a potentially hot substance into a cold jar is asking for trouble.